# how to handle UITextView Keyboard for ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How to get call keyboard methods when UITextView is clicked.

How to get keyboard appears and disappears when UITextview selected.

I need keyboard delegates methods to call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what you mean, but you can use **becomeFirstResponder** and **resignFirstResponder** to control displaying the keyboard.